# Passing list from view to controller MVC3

Tags: forms, list, asp.net-mvc-3, post

after deep searching I couldn't find any solution.
I have a Ajax.BeginForm which needs to pass a list containing information about the checked rows.

UnitsChecked Class (Model)

```
public class UnitsChecked
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public TaxiTV.Data.Entity.Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

ReportsVM (View Model Class)

```
public class ReportsVM 
{
    public IEnumerable<UnitsChecked> UnitList { get; set; }
    public ReportsVM()
    {
         UnitList = new List<UnitsChecked>();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml (View)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetReports", "Reports", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ReportList", LoadingElementId = "loader" })) 
{
    <table class="tableBorder">
        <tr>
            <th>Choose
            </th>
            <th>
                @Resources.IMEI
            </th>
            <th>
                @Resources.SIM
            </th>
            <th>
                @Resources.Name
            </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UnitList.Count(); i++ )
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UnitList.ElementAt(i).IsChecked, new { @class = "checkboxListener" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.UnitList.ElementAt(i).Unit.IMEI)
                    @Html.Hidden("zzz", Model.UnitList.ElementAt(i)) <---- This line
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.UnitList.ElementAt(i).Unit.SIM
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.UnitList.ElementAt(i).Unit.Person.FirstName @Model.UnitList.ElementAt(i).Unit.Person.LastName
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

The main and most important line is where the arrow points.
Using Fiddler2 I managed to see that all the list of UnitsChecked is sent one by one.
The following controller says the "zzz" is null.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetReports(ReportsVM rvm, List<UnitsChecked> zzz)
    {
```

Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change property `UnitList` to typeof `IList<UnitsChecked>` and then in the view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.UnitList.Count; i++ )
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UnitList[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkboxListener" })
  @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.UnitList.[i].Unit.IMEI)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.UnitList.[i].Unit.SomeProperty) // for any properties of Unit that you want posted back
}
```

This will correctly name you controls with indexers so they can be bound to a collection, i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="UnitList[0].IsChecked" .. value="True" />
<input type="hidden" name="UnitList[0].IsChecked" .. value="False" />
<input type="checkbox" name="UnitList[1].IsChecked" .. value="True" />
<input type="hidden" name="UnitList[1].IsChecked" .. value="False" />
```

Your current use of `.ElementAt(i)` is giving the controls duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and `name` attributes (so cant be bound to a collection).

Your controller then needs to be just

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetReports(ReportsVM rvm)
```